What size quick disconnect for a Mr cool advantage 36K single zone, also what size breaker
What size breaker and quick disconnect do I need for my MrCool Advantage 4 generation 36K BTU’s single zone split unit

The online instruction available on the Depot website say "The size of the power supply cable, signal
cable, fuse, and switch needed is determined
by the maximum current of the unit. The
maximum current is indicated on the nameplate
located on the side panel of the unit. Refer to
this nameplate to choose the right cable, fuse,
or switch." What does the label say? https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/1e/1e50e926-056e-4959-ab5b-f7831e927c48.pdf page 23

I would expect it would specify minimum circuit ampacity of less than 20A, and max overcurrent protection of 35A (generally 1A per 1K btu), but 30A would work just fine  as long as you don't have low voltage issues.

It's not a quick disconnect.  It is a disconnect switch.  If your logic is "I'll find out the smallest I can use because that will surely be cheaper than a larger one" I don't know, this is hard to beat. https://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-60-Amp-240-Volt-Non-Fuse-Metallic-AC-Disconnect-TFN60RCP/100674085
